# How to read in Pandas DataFrame while ignoring index and column labels?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A while back I made a DataFrame full of ints with strings for column and index labels and saved it as a .csv. 
Something like this:

```
     A   B  C
 A   1   5  8
 B   5   2  4
 C   8   4  0
```

Now I am trying to read the csv and perform operations on it. In order to do that, I have to get rid of those labels. I have tried using drop but they don't go away. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='path',header=None,index_col=False)
print(df.head())
```

This is what comes out:

```
                                       0   ...                  12
0                                     NaN  ...   10.1021/nn502895s
1                       10.1063/1.4973245  ...  3.1641066942926606
2         10.3891/acta.chem.scand.26-0333  ...  3.8644527240688675
3                        10.1063/1.463096  ...  2.9273855677735448
4  10.1146/annurev-physchem-040412-110130  ...  6.1534904155247325
```

How do I get rid of the labels (the strings)?
Thank you!

Comment: Which string in the output are you trying to get rid of? Could you please mention input too?
To get rid of columns , you may remove the header=None parameter when reading the csv.

Comment: I am trying to get rid of the leftmost column and top row. So all of the strings that start with "10." . The input is the same idea as the one with A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `skiprows=1` for avoid header of csv to first line of `DataFrame`, then add `index_col=[0]` for correct parsing index and last remove it by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, skiprows=1, index_col=[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   1  2  3
0  1  5  8
1  5  2  4
2  8  4  0
```